# Via Remember me always return false

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, remember-me

Before I posted this, I did some searching but still I don't know it always return false. My code is below

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember"/> {{ trans('login.text_remember_me') }}
```

controller

```
$remember = ($request->has('remember')) ? true : false;

if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember))
```

Then after successful logged-in. I checked the **dd(Auth::viaRemember());** and it return false. Even changed my config/session.php setting **'expire_on_close' => true from false**.

> ***Basically what I want is when the user tick the remember me checkbox I will set the session lifetime to 3 days else to 1 day only.***

Updated

From **$request->all()** here are the result after clicking the login button with checked remember me

```
array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "...."
  "email" => "myemail@gmail.com"
  "password" => "...."
  "remember" => "on"
  "uri" => ""
  "code" => ""
]
```

then I removed in my dashboard controller I checked the viaRemember method

```
dd(Auth::viaRemember()); // result: false
```

Comment: are you getting the proper value at controller end, means you checked the Box, you getting the value ? add your `request` dump array into your question so can give you suggestion

Comment: yes, I tried to dump the request for the "remember" before the if condition and it showed true but when I called viaRemember it showed false.. :(

Comment: I asks you to share your Dump results

Comment: I updated my question to add the dump result. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Update your this line

```
$remember = ($request->has('remember')) ? true : false;
```

to this, and then check.

```
$remember = ($request->get('remember') == 'on') ? true : false;
```

Comment: same result. It always return false. I'm using laravel 5.1 just in case. :(

Comment: replace this `$request->input('remember')` with this `$request->get('remember')` and then try it

Comment: still the same result. :(. I checked the value of the remember me before submitting it and it did get the correct boolean but the weird part is when I checked using viaRemember() it always return false. :(

Comment: rewrite your this line `if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true))` pass `true` directly and then check that `viaRemember()` is working or not ? can you share your `users` table structure ? in your users Table, there must be column name `remember_token`, because it stores the remember me token in DB

Comment: After successful log-in it still it remains false. I have the column remember_token on by table user and i checked the value of the column and it has a value in it. Also I checked my entire repo if I maybe overriding the Auth::attempt somewhere but found nothing. :(

Comment: Kindly delete older cookies, then try it

Comment: same result. Tried deleting cookies in my browser and also used incognito mode. It still return false. If it may help my session driver is file and expire_on_close is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

add "id = remember me" to input field

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"/>
```

not sure.